# Why do electric field lines bend towards the normal of a linear homogeneous dielectric sphere?

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, polarization, dielectric

[image]Why do the field lines of the uniform external field bend towards the normal of the linear homogeneous dielectric sphere as shown in the diagram?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The external field causes a polarization in the sphere. The resulting dipole field superimposed on the external field is what you are seeing/what you are asking about.

Longer, more basic explanation:
Think of the polarization in the sphere as positive charges being pushed towards the upper end of the sphere (in the above picture) and negative charges being pushed to the lower end. Of course, in the case of a dielectric, electrostatic induction does not causes charges to move, but only atoms and molecules to be polarized; the effect will be the same: a net accumulation of (equal in magnitude!) positive charges at the top, negative charges at the bottom.

Now look at a point outside the sphere. A test charge there will experience a field that is the sum of the external field and the one caused by the induced charges. While the external field is purely vertical, the field caused by the induced charges is not. Let's say it has two contributions, one each from either the positive or the negative charge accumulated at the top or the bottom of the sphere. Both contributions are proportional to $\pm \frac{q}{r^2}$ wherein $\pm q$ is the accumulated charge at the end of the sphere and $r$ the distance to the point where we are measuring the field, and pointing towards the bottom of the sphere (negative charge, attracting a positive test charge) or away from the top of the sphere (positive charge, repelling a positive test charge). That is they have horizontal contributions.

At all points that have different distances to the top and bottom of the sphere (which is all points except the ones on the horizontal symmetry plane) the distances to top and bottom of the square are different and thus the horizontal components of the field caused by the induced charge do not cancel.

For example, near the bottom of the square, the field produced by induced charge is dominated by the attraction towards the negative charges at the bottom of the square, which is why it is pointing inwards.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Because there is a surface charge density:

$$ \rho_{bound}(r, \theta, \phi)\propto \delta(R)\cos\theta \propto Y_1^0(\theta, \phi)$$

If that is insufficient, imagine subtracting a dipole field from a uniform field (outside the sphere).